# Assign value to variable using nested condition in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to assign values to variable using nested condition in ansible, Can some one help to know how this can be achieved i am not sure how to use if else in roles , In below Example: I want to a
to set my_host variable with below logic

sudo code for the logic I want to achieve in play

```
 if component.Comp1.SubComp1.host defined
   set my_host = component.Comp1.SubComp1.host
 elif component.Comp1.host defined;
   set  my_host = component.Comp1.host
 else
   set my_host = host
 endif
```

inventory file

```
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
    host3
    

  vars:
    app: myApp
    host:host3
    basePath: /home/foo/test/
    
    component:
      Comp1:
        SubComp1:
          host: host2
          basePath: /home/foo/test1/
  
        SubComp2:
          host: host2
          basePath: /home/foo/test1/
  
      Comp2:
        host:host1
        basePath: /home/bar/test1/
        SubComp1:
  
        SubComp2:
          host: host3
          basePath: /home/bar/test1/
```

play

```
    - include_role:
        name: create_config
      vars:
        VENUE: "{{ play_item.key }}"
        COMPONENT_NAME: comp1
        dest_folder: "{{ play_item.value.basePath}}"
        my_host: "{{ play_item.value.host}}"

      when:  my_host  == ansible_fqdn and include_Component.comp1 is defined

      with_items:
        - "{{component.comp1| dict2items }}"

      loop_control:
        loop_var: play_item
```

Comment: See [mre] on how to minimize the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify the variables a bit

```py
 if SubComp1 defined
   set my_host = SubComp1
 elif Comp1 defined;
   set  my_host = Comp1
 else
   set my_host = 'host'
 endif
```

In Ansible, use *default* filter, e.g.

```yaml
my_host: "{{ SubComp1|d(Comp1|d('host')) }}"
```

gives by default

```yaml
  my_host: host
```

If *Comp1* is defined

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml -e Comp1='Comp1'

  my_host: Comp1
```

If *SubComp1* is defined

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml -e SubComp1='SubComp1'

  my_host: SubComp1
```

Comment: Thank you so much ..  This quite resolves my query